# Type name already in use - Unable to use Rename Symbol command to correct Apex class name capitalisation

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, rename-symbol, refactoring

I use Apex PMD, one of the rules is:

> Class names should begin with an uppercase character (rule: Code Style-ClassNamingConventions)
>   See: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_codestyle.html#classnamingconventions

When I try and used VS Code Rename Symbol F2 command to change:

```
public class myClass { }
```

to

```
public class MyClass { }
```

I get this error:

> Type name already in use: ...

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I would suggest a global search and replace rather than refactoring. Recall that Apex is case insensitive so you are basically renaming a class to itself and you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like VS Code rename check is case insensitive, this leads to this error.
As a workaround, you can perform rename in 2 phases

1. Rename myClass to myClassNew (deploy all changes to the server)
2. Rename myClassNew to MyClass.

Also as a workaround, you can use another tool for editing Apex code.
You can try JetForcer (I participate in developing this plugin) it supports lots of refactorings and handle this case properly.

You can read about them here https://jetforcer.com/pages/features/refactorings

Comment: Michael, please make sure to call out your affiliation to this product in your posts. See the [promotion policy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Posts that don't disclose an affiliation are removed as spam. You can make an [edit] to address this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!